# reading and parsing midi files in c++

Tags: c++, parsing, midi

I need to read and parse midi date, what I did is :

1- Reading a midi from a midi device (I used RTMIDI)
2- Parsing midi file (I used jdksmidi)

This is not really efficient since I used two libraries thus 2 different programs, what I want is one library that does the reading and parsing. Does anyone know such a library ?

I tried JUCE, it is a good one but the problem is that you should use EDI (Introducer), which doesn't really help me. Both Jack and Portmidi don't do parsing  only IO.

Thanks,
Mimi.

Comment: I have no real know-how in the midi world but the specs are public and and in theory you should be able to code your own library after reading the specs. Also it depends on what you want to do, jdksmidi is GPL, so I think that you want to code an open and free application ( while releasing the source code ).

Comment: Why do you think there should be a single library to do it? If I want to scan an image or capture video, that's probably going to be a different library than if I want to read an image off of disk. This is the same situation.

Comment: How is using two libraries considered as `not really efficient`? In what particular aspect is it inefficient?

Comment: Because I have two programs that use different data structure and I need to link them somehow, the solution that I found now is using "ALSA", i am not really familiar with that, but it is the only solution that I can find right now.